# Using a specific wlan interface with nmcli

Tags: networking, networkmanager

I want to connect to a specific network via bssid with nmcli. Using the command:

```
nmcli d wifi connect [BSSID]
```

However this used the wlan0 interface. Is there a way I can force a network interface. (Say wlan1 per example?)
Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Not an NM user but have you tried using the specific interface name in place of "wifi"?

Answer (score 2):

`man nmcli` on Debian 11 (`nmcli` version 1.30.0) gives this format for the `nmcli d[evice] wifi connect` sub-command:

> `wifi connect (B)SSID [password password] [wep-key-type {key | phrase}] [ifname ifname] [bssid BSSID] [name name] [private {yes | no}] [hidden {yes | no}]`

So, if you want to add the interface name, the syntax would be:

```
nmcli d wifi connect BSSID ifname wlan1
```

Of course, if you use a different distribution, it might have a different version of `nmcli` with a modified syntax.

Comment: I do this too but I have observed one issue. When I open nmtui to see the details of the connection, I cannot see the device mac address in the device attribute. When I connect it through GUI, I see it

Comment: @ShravyaBoggarapu You might want to make a bug report to your distribution about it then. I'm not a NetworkManager developer, and as far as I know, Unix&Linux StackExchange has no particular ties to [NetworkManager development or issue tracking](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/NetworkManager/NetworkManager/-/issues) - we're all just users each asking for advice or sharing our knowledge here.

Comment: Yeah, I was wondering if this was an issue that only I experienced or I was missing something